# How to prevent Vim from translating C-j into C-m when started by the zle widget `edit-command-line`?

Tags: zsh, vim

I have the following code in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey '^X^E' edit-command-line
```

It binds the `edit-command-line` zle widget to the keysequence `C-x C-e`.
The widget is described in `man zshcontrib` (section  `ZLE FUNCTIONS`, subsection `Widgets`):

> edit-command-line
>          Edit the command line using your visual editor, as in ksh.
>
> ```
>           bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
> ```

The purpose is to be able to edit the current shell command line, in the default editor, by pressing `C-x C-e`, similar to what the readline function `edit-and-execute-command` does (`man bash`, section `READLINE`, subsection `Commands for Manipulating the History`).

> edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)
>          Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands.  Bash attempts
>          to invoke $VISUAL, $EDITOR, and emacs as the editor, in that order.

My default editor is Vim `8.1` (patches `1-538` included).
I have Vim mappings, using the keys `C-h`, `C-j`, `C-k`, `C-l`, to move the focus to neighbour windows.
They can be boiled down to:

```
nnoremap <c-h> :<c-u>wincmd h<cr>
nnoremap <c-j> :<c-u>wincmd j<cr>
nnoremap <c-k> :<c-u>wincmd k<cr>
nnoremap <c-l> :<c-u>wincmd l<cr>
```

They all work as expected in a regular Vim instance (started by executing `$ vim`).
But `C-j` doesn't work as expected when Vim was started by `edit-command-line`.

When I press `C-x C-e` while on the shell command line, zsh starts Vim. If I split the window by executing `:split`, then press `C-k` to move to the top window, I get two windows, and the focus is moved to the top one. But then, if I press `C-j` to get back to the bottom window, nothing happens.

I don't know whether it's the cause of the issue, but if I try to insert a literal `C-j` in a Vim buffer (by pressing `C-v C-j`), `^M` is displayed (the caret notation for a carriage return). In a regular Vim instance (started by executing `$ vim`), inserting a literal `C-j` results in a character whose caret notation is `^@` (a NUL).

I can reproduce the issue with this minimal `~/.zshrc`:

```
export EDITOR=vim
autoload -Uz edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey '^X^E' edit-command-line
```

And this minimal `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <c-j> :echom 'C-j has been pressed'<cr>
```

Pressing `C-x C-e` on the zsh command line starts Vim, then pressing `C-j` should print and log the message:

```
C-j has been pressed
```

But nothing happens.

I can't reproduce the issue in bash, nor with Neovim (`v0.3.2-752-g4d7c7f9`).
Besides, inserting a literal `C-j` in Vim, when the latter was started from bash after pressing `C-x C-e`, results in a NUL (`^@`). Same thing when Neovim is started from bash or zsh after pressing `C-x C-e`.

```
┌────────┬──────┬─────┐
│        │ bash │ zsh │
├────────┼──────┼─────┤
│ Vim    │ ^@   │ ^M  │
├────────┼──────┼─────┤
│ Neovim │ ^@   │ ^@  │
└────────┴──────┴─────┘
```

I thought that maybe some Vim terminal option was not properly configured, so I captured the output of:

```
:set termcap
```

from Vim started by `$ vim`, and from Vim started by `C-x C-e`.
But the output is identical in both cases:

```
--- Terminal codes ---

  t_AL=^[[%p1%dL      t_DL=^[[%p1%dM      t_mr=^[[7m          t_se=^[[27m         t_us=^[[4m
  t_al=^[[L           t_dl=^[[M           t_ms=y              t_Sf=               t_ut=
  t_bc=               t_EC=               t_nd=^[[C           t_SH=               t_vb=^[g
  t_BE=               t_EI=^[[2 q         t_op=^[[39;49m      t_SI=^[[6 q         t_vi=^[[?25l
  t_BD=               t_fs=^G             t_RF=               t_Si=               t_VS=
  t_cd=^[[J           t_GP=               t_RB=               t_so=^[[7m          t_vs=^[[34l
  t_ce=^[[K           t_IE=               t_RC=               t_SR=^[[4 q         t_WP=
  t_cl=^[[H^[[J       t_IS=               t_RI=^[[%p1%dC      t_sr=^[M            t_WS=
  t_Ce=               t_ke=^[[?1l^[>      t_Ri=               t_ST=               t_xn=y
  t_Co=256            t_ks=^[[?1h^[=      t_RS=               t_Te=               t_xs=
  t_CS=               t_le=^H             t_RT=               t_Ts=               t_ZH=^[[3m
  t_CV=               t_mb=^[[5m          t_RV=               t_ts=^[]0;          t_ZR=^[[23m
  t_da=               t_md=^[[1m          t_Sb=               t_u7=               t_8f=
  t_db=               t_me=^[[0m          t_SC=               t_ue=^[[24m         t_8b=
  t_AB=^[[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m
  t_AF=^[[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m
  t_cm=^[[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH
  t_Cs=^[]12;%p1%s^G
  t_cs=^[[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr
  t_te=^[[2 q^[[?1004l^[[?1049l
  t_ti=^[[2 q^[[?1004h^[[?1049h
  t_ve=^[[34h^[[?25h

--- Terminal keys ---

t_#2 <S-Home>    ^[[1;2H   t_k6 <F6>        ^[[17~    t_kh <Home>      ^[[1~          <ð>        ^[p
t_#4 <S-Left>    ^[[1;2D   t_k7 <F7>        ^[[18~    t_kl <Left>      ^[OD           <ô>        ^[t
t_%i <S-Right>   ^[[1;2C   t_k8 <F8>        ^[[19~    t_kr <Right>     ^[OC           <õ>        ^[u
t_*7 <S-End>     ^[[1;2F   t_k9 <F9>        ^[[20~    t_ku <Up>        ^[OA           <ù>        ^[y
t_@7 <End>       ^[[4~     t_k; <F10>       ^[[21~         <á>        ^[a            <ú>        ^[z
t_F1 <F11>       ^[[23~    t_kB <S-Tab>     ^[[Z           <â>        ^[b            <Mouse>     ^[[M
t_F2 <F12>       ^[[24~    t_kD <Del>       ^[[3~          <ä>        ^[d            <S-F18>     ^[[O
t_k1 <F1>        ^[OP      t_kI <Insert>    ^[[2~          <å>        ^[e            <S-F19>     ^[[I
t_k2 <F2>        ^[OQ      t_kN <PageDown>  ^[[6~          <æ>        ^[f            <xUp>       ^[[1;*A
t_k3 <F3>        ^[OR      t_kP <PageUp>    ^[[5~          <ç>        ^[g            <xDown>     ^[[1;*B
t_k4 <F4>        ^[OS      t_kb <BS>        ^?             <í>        ^[m            <xLeft>     ^[[1;*D
t_k5 <F5>        ^[[15~    t_kd <Down>      ^[OB           <î>        ^[n            <xRight>    ^[[1;*C
```

The output of `$ stty -a` is also identical in bash and zsh:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 33; columns 119; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

I'm using `zsh 5.6.2-dev-1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Is there a Vim or zsh option which should be set to prevent Vim from translating `C-j` into `C-m` when started by the zle widget `edit-command-line`?

Comment: Zsh modifies stty settings while zle is active. Running `stty` from a prompt shows the settings when running commands, not the settings during command line edition. This looks like a bug where it doesn't properly restore stty settings when it runs a command from within command line edition.

Comment: @Gilles,  `zsh` does redirect stdin from /dev/null inside user-defined widgets, but `edit-command-line` does a `exec < /dev/tty`, but does not restore the non-zle settings, so the _bug_ if more with that `edit-command-line` widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your `$EDITOR` to a script or function that does `stty -a`, you'll notice that the terminal settings at the time `vim` is called by that `edit-command-line` are those of zle (where `inlcr` which causes the terminal device driver to translate NL to CR is on among other things).

`^J` is the newline character, so binding it is a bit delicate.

Here, you can work around it by defining a `vim` function as:

```
vim() STTY=sane command vim "$@"
```

Or add edit the `STTY=sane` (or `STTY=-inlcr`) to `edit-command-line`.